# Why does changing a field from `&'a [u8]` to `&'a mut [u8]` cause a lifetime error?

Tags: rust

This code compiles:

```
struct BufRef<'a> {
    buf: &'a [u8],
}

struct Foo<'a> {
    buf_ref: BufRef<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Foo<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [u8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let result = &self.buf_ref.buf;
        Some(result)
    }
}
```

However, if I change `BufRef` to:

```
struct BufRef<'a> {
    buf: &'a mut [u8],
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src\main.rs:13:16
   |
13 |         let result = &self.buf_ref.buf;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 12:5...
  --> src\main.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
13 | |         let result = &self.buf_ref.buf;
14 | |         Some(result)
15 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src\main.rs:13:16
   |
13 |         let result = &self.buf_ref.buf;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 9:6...
  --> src\main.rs:9:6
   |
9  | impl<'a> Iterator for Foo<'a> {
   |      ^^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected std::iter::Iterator
              found std::iter::Iterator
```

Why does changing the field to `&'a mut [u8]` cause the error?

Also, what does the compiler mean by this:

```
...so that the types are compatible:
               expected std::iter::Iterator
                  found std::iter::Iterator
```

Comment: Please take a look at a [Streaming Iterator](https://docs.rs/streaming-iterator/0.1.4/streaming_iterator/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what is misleading you is that your code has a collapsed reference.

Your `next` function is basically equivalent to this code:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    let result: &&'a [u8] = &self.buf_ref.buf;
    Some(result)
}
```

This works because the double reference collapses to a single reference. In this case the double reference only obfuscates the code. Just write:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    Some(self.buf_ref.buf)
}
```

And this works because references are always `Copy`.

But now what happens when you change your definition to `&'a mut`? You are probably guessing right now... mutable references are *not* `Copy`, so the same simple code will give you an easy-to-read error message:

> cannot move out of `self.buf_ref.buf` which is behind a mutable reference

Naturally, you can reborrow a mutable ref as a const one, and then try to return it, but unfortunately this will not work because the the re-borrow cannot use the same lifetime as the mutable variable, it must be strictly smaller (or you could alias the pointed values). The compiler assigns the lifetime of this re-borrow as that of the `next` function, but now you cannot return this borrow, because it is a local reference!

Unfortunately, I don't know of any safe way to make your code compile. In fact I'm quite sure that it would create an unsound API. That is, if you managed to compile your code, then this safe code would create undefined behavior:

```
fn main() {
    let mut buf = vec![1,2,3];
    let buf_ref = BufRef { buf: &mut buf };
    let mut foo = Foo { buf_ref };
    let x: &[u8] = foo.next().unwrap();
    //note that x's lifetime is that of buf, foo is not borrowed
    //x and foo.buf_ref.buf alias the same memory!
    //but the latter is mutable    
    println!("{}", x[0]); //prints 1
    foo.buf_ref.buf[0] = 4;
    println!("{}", x[0]); //prints what?
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that I can't implement an iterator which returns an item which is backed by a mutable buffer referenced by the iterator?

Comment: @Shmoopy: AIUI, it is impossible because it would allow to alias the mutable reference. To do that you'd need somehow to keep the iterator borrowed when calling `next()` (`fn next<'s>(&'s self) -> Option<&'s T>`), but that is not how the trait is defined.

Comment: Iterators in rust generally can't return items which borrow from themselves. There's a crate called [`streaming_iterator`](https://docs.rs/streaming-iterator/0.1.4/streaming_iterator/) which solves this though.